# The effect of oversampling on the positive predictive value

Tags: sampling, validation, sensitivity-specificity

I need to calculate the positive predictive value for a validation set for a rare event. The problem is that the validation set was oversampled for the rare event. The event occurs in 5 percent of the population, however the oversampling has adjusted it to be in 50 percent of the sample.

How does the oversampling effect the calculation of the ppv?

Comment: This article explains that you need to adjust the odds (not the probabilities) by the fraction your oversample by: https://yiminwu.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/how-to-undo-oversampling-explained/.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, probabilities are inflated now because of oversampling. you can divide predictions by 10 as you had 10 folded the positive class. or there are different ways of re- calibrating probabilities like -

https://quinonero.net/Publications/predicting-clicks-facebook.pdf

( section 6.3 -model re calibration)

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? This would mean the highest rating the classifier could provide would be 0.1 which doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: sure- https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/41159.pdf

Comment: go to section 7- calibrating predictions.

Comment: That article suggests using isotonic regression to calibrate models. It certainly does not suggest dividing your predictions by a constant and also seems unrelated to oversampling in preprocessing.

Comment: For example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/257507/40604

Comment: Hey @Dan, yes you are correct that it shouldn't be divided directly by 10. But recalibation of probabilities are required. I have done lot of research already. Read the another Facebook click prediction - https://quinonero.net/Publications/predicting-clicks-facebook.pdf ( if you go to recalculation of predictions section ) .

Comment: then as it stands, your answer is incorrect (and misleading). I suggest you edit it or delete it.

Comment: edited , but yes, probabilities are inflated and must be re-calibrated.

Comment: No one is arguing otherwise. But your answer contains an entirely incorrect method for the adjustment and does nothing to explain how to correctly make the adjustment.

Comment: You need to pull the equation from that paper out and write it in your answer, contextualized to this problem. Otherwise you've just provided a link which is not an acceptable form of answer on stack exchange.

Comment: no , no you are right, we should come to right solution but  u dont need a method. This is pure intuition based, If you can think. a as independent has 1,0 as outcome. if you have just 2 rows with 0, 1 so probability of both events is .5, if you over sample class 1 by adding 1 more row, probabilities of getting 1 will be 2/3  which is indeed inflated. isn't it?

Comment: sure.. will update answer now.